# OpenLayers - cannot set layer opacity

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, vector, layers, transparency-opacity

I have the following problem: by default, you can simply change the opacity of layer by writing for example:

```
layer.setOpacity(0.3);
```

But when I add it to my map SelectFeature controls, my layer is put to a thing like `OpenLayers.Vector.RootContainer`. From this moment I can't set opacity of my layer.
I tried lots of ways but none of them work:

```
myVectorRootContainer.layers[0].setOpacity(0.4);
myVectorRootContainer.setOpacity(0.4);
```

Is there an option for using `SelectFeature` controls without `RootContainers`? Or a way to change opacity of a container?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found the solution.
I use `deactivate` and `activate` on my SelectFeature controls, when I need to set opacity.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is logged in GitHub, along with the patch to set opacity on a Rootcontainer - see https://github.com/openlayers/ol2/pull/1178

Override code below:

```
OpenLayers.Layer.Vector.prototype.setOpacity = function (opacity) {
    if (opacity != this.opacity) {
        this.opacity = opacity;
        var element = this.renderer.root;
        OpenLayers.Util.modifyDOMElement(element, null, null, null, null,
                null, null, opacity);
        if (this.map != null) {
            this.map.events.triggerEvent("changelayer", {
                layer: this,
                property: "opacity"
            });
        }
    }
};
```